# Compling SelectDirectory Third Overload with Delphi 10

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

Why won't this compile?  It seems simple but I do not understand... is the array of string the problem?  The error is:

```
[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(94): E2250 There is no overloaded version of 'SelectDirectory' that can be called with these arguments.
```

Here is the code:

```
{
function SelectDirectory(const StartDirectory: string; out Directories: TArray<string>; Options: TSelectDirFileDlgOpts = [];
  const Title: string = ''; const FolderNameLabel: string = ''; const OkButtonLabel: string = ''): Boolean; overload;
}

procedure TForm2.Browse1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  iStartFolder: string;
  iDirectories: Array of string;
  iSelectedFolder: string;
begin
  iStartFolder := DesktopFolder;
  if SelectDirectory(iStartFolder, iDirectories,
    [sdHidePinnedPlaces, sdNoDereferenceLinks, sdForceShowHidden,
    sdAllowMultiselect], 'Select Folder', 'Folder', 'Ok') then
    ShowMessage(iDirectories[0]);
end;
```

Comment: Ok Jason... you were correct.  Thank-you

Comment: Because `TArray<string>` is not the same type as `Array of string`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second parameter of the third `SelectDirectory()` overload is an `out` parameter, so you must provide a variable that is the same type as the parameter.  You are trying to pass an `array of string` variable where a `System.TArray<String>` variable is expected, thus the error.  Use this instead:

```
procedure TForm2.Browse1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  iStartFolder: string;
  iDirectories: TArray<string>;
  iSelectedFolder: string;
begin
  iStartFolder := DesktopFolder;
  if SelectDirectory(iStartFolder, iDirectories,
    [sdHidePinnedPlaces, sdNoDereferenceLinks, sdForceShowHidden,
    sdAllowMultiselect], 'Select Folder', 'Folder', 'Ok') then
    ShowMessage(iDirectories[0]);
end;
```

Although `TArray<String>` is just an alias for `array of string`, they are effectively different types when used with `out` parameters.

Comment: Why the down vote?  It is almost impossible to post anything here at all without someone being negative rather than positive....

Comment: @Bill: First, why are you asking Remy? He clearly didn't downvote, or he wouldn't have answered. Second, I didn't downvote, but it might be because you posted a function declaration that asked you to provide a `TArray<string>` and code that did something totally different (use an `array of string`); a simple (and careful) reading of the function declaration should have answered your question. Delphi is strongly typed. `TArray<string>` and `array of string` are not the same - the first is a generic array of string, the second a dynamic array of string.

Comment: @KenWhite: `TArray<String>` is just an alias for `array of String`: `type TArray<T> = array of T;`. But, in this case, where an `out` parameter is involved, they are treated different.

Comment: *you must provide a variable that is the same type as the parameter*, well, you can also typecast there but it's better to pass the exact type.